# how to fix CS0201 razor issue

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. Here I am trying to loop though picture collection but in `img` tag razor intellisense telling syntax is wrong. error is:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

```
foreach (var theme in Model.Themes)
{
  <img src="https://pic.example.com/@{theme.Id.ToString() + "/" + theme.BannerName;} " alt="Alternate Text" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
}
```

Comment: It's probably that `;` after `BannerName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change to `string.Format` as

```
@foreach (var theme in Model.Themes)
 {
        <img src="https://pic.example.com/@(string.Format("{0}/{1}",theme.Id, theme.BannerName))" alt="Alternate Text" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps explain why? Also that `.ToString()` isn't neccessary